# How to set `compileOnly` dependency in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Android (gradle) has an option to declare a dependency in a module as compileOnly, meaning that the module depends on it, but it will be provided by another module.

For example: The app depends on module A, but module A has a compileOnly dependency on module B, so the app needs to provide B as well.

I want to ship a module without a specific dependency (in my case a framework) and then the end user can add both - my module and the missing dependency of my module.

How to set this for a closed source .framework?

Tried SPM and cocoapods but with no luck...

Comment: Could you explain why no luck with SPM and cocoapods. Duplicating symbols linkage error?